# FFMPEG - it takes frames from .avi but doesn't work for mp4

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I run the following PHP code in a loop in order to extract the frame from 10th second from a list of video (avi & mp4):

```
$command = "$ffmpegpath -y -i $input  -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:$fromdurasec -y $output";
```

It seems that it generates frames for avi files but not for mp4.

When I run the command manually in command-line it works as expected (as in takes the frame and saves it in folder). Please find below the full log of ffmpeg process:

```
ffmpeg version 3.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libvorbis -- 
enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-gnutls --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc
libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'new test video.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
encoder         : Lavf52.93.0
Duration: 00:22:19.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3560 kb/s
Stream #0:0(rus): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 3427 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(rus): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
[swscaler @ 0x20b0140] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'newtest.jpg':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
Stream #0:0(rus): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
  encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 mjpeg
Side data:
  unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
Enter command: <target>|all <time>|-1 <command>[ <argument>]
```

Comment: Meaning that FFMPEG does not know how to decode your MP4 video. What's the output of `ffmpeg -version`, then try to get info about the input MP4 using some tool like MediaInfo (https://superuser.com/questions/595177/how-to-retrieve-video-file-information-from-command-line-under-linux). Post both outputs here.

Comment: Does it work as expected if you run the exact same command without PHP? Unscripted, manually, in a command-line interface. Also, show the complete log from the ffmpeg process.

Comment: Hi, I have updated with the ffmped-version output and the complete log from ffmpeg process in command-line interface

Comment: Now show the log from the ffmpeg process in the PHP script that does not work.